# Another way to think about the * operator/splat?

Tags: python

I couldn't find anything explaining this operator in a way I've seen it used, so I just wanted to make sure I understand it correctly and help those like myself who aren't programming wizards.

Consider that we can write

`tree.delete(*tree.get_children())`

and

```
for i in tree.get_children():
    tree.delete(i)
```

to do the same thing. In this case, it seems like `tree.delete` has been programmed to accept an argument of arbitrary length to accomplish the same thing as a for loop. Is this popular to do? Is this kosher to do?

`edit:` here is my solution to what I meant to answer for the first part

```
def func(*numbers):
    return list(map(lambda x: x + 1, numbers))


old = [1,2,3]
new = []

for i in old:
    new.append(i + 1)

print(func(*old) == new)
```

`for` loop and `func` are equivalent here, but is there a reason why we might prefer one over the other?

Comment: No. Did you try? What happened?

Comment: feel it took you a lot longer to type this out than to actually try it.

Comment: don't be afraid of the python documentation, https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments

Comment: Okay I get it, the function isn't built to work that way. I guess I meant given the appropriate function is it equivalent to a for loop? I've read the documentation, I just wanted to check if I was understanding the concept correctly, not if my code would run.

Comment: I don't get your question. Are you asking how to do it? Or if it is wise to do it? It can be done, but if it is good practice or not, I am afraid is strongly opinion-based.

Answer (score 2):

`f(*old)` is equivalent to calling `f(1,2,3)`.  This will raise an error as `f` can't take more than one parameter.

You can see this is functionally different from your list version.  If you want to rewrite your list to something easier/prettier you can use list comprehension and go

```
new = [ f(i) for i in old ]
```

There is also `map`

```
new = list(map(f,old))
```

Answer (score 0):

> `for` loop and `func` are equivalent here, but is there a reason why we might prefer one over the other?

Are you wondering about a difference in performance? You still need to loop over all the elements. Outside or inside the method, the loop is the same, so in general I would say there is no real advantage in one solution rather than the other in term of performance.

The preference should depend on other factors. For example, do you foresee that you will need to delete these `three.children` in loops a lot in your program? If so, better let the function to loop over them rather than write a lot of times:

```
for i in tree.get_children():
    tree.delete(i)
```

in your code.